# How to set up a proxy in React app without create-react-app when deploying to Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, proxy

I created a React app based on the template of mine (https://github.com/MikeMikhailov/React-Template). Now I'm trying to deploy it to Heroku, with a connection to Express REST Api. I wonder, how can I set up a proxy, so that all requests to /api/* are given an origin of my backend. I already tried setting up a static.json file with

```
"proxies": {
  "/api" : {
    "origin": "https://${BACKEND_URL}/api"
  }
}
```

but it didn't seem to work, as I was continually getting 405 as requests were made to the /api of front-end.

```
index_bundle.js?bace5e170912d902f943:12 POST https://${FRONTEND_URL}/api/auth/signup 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

Is any other way of doing this without using create-react-app?

**static.json**

```
{
  "root": "dist/",
  "routes": {
    "/**":"index.html"
  },
  "proxies": {
    "/api": {
      "origin": "https://${BACKEND_URL}/api"
    }
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "warbler-client",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "./src/index.jsx",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --mode development --hot",
    "build": "node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.prod.js --mode production",
    "start": "node_modules/.bin/http-server ./dist"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "http-server": "^0.12.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "ky": "^0.19.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.13.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
    "react-moment": "^0.9.7",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-router-prop-types": "^1.0.4",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.4.1",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.88.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.7",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.7",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.7",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "css-loader": "^3.4.2",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.10.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.19.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "1.7.0",
    "favicons-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^5.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.11",
    "js-beautify": "^1.10.3",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.9.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "webpack": "^4.42.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
  },
}
```

Comment: You want to add a proxy configuration for http-server / webpack / webpack-dev-server. For http-server you can use the -P flag to route ALL requests which don't resolve to the endpoint.

Comment: For others, I'm not that familiar, but I'm sure they have reverse proxying. Check the documentation.

Comment: A proxy that you would get with CRA is only meant for development purposes. Does you express serve both the api endpoints and the react application static built files? If it doesn’t, why not just point the react requests at the absolute url? You can point to /api when mode/env is dev and to the actual absolute url when not in mode/env dev. Is this to get around CORS issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

The thing was that by default, Heroku detected the Node.js app, successfully built it, and served it through my start script. So it didn't make use of static.json. To solve the issue, just add a Static Website Buildpack on Heroku after the Node.js one. I hope this helps somebody!